# Ember Blueprint skip confirmation

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, blueprint

I use the ember blueprint.Install(options) method to create files based on blueprint, but this causes overwrite questions for existing and not identical files. I allways want to skip that kind of questions, is that possible?

Is it maybe possible to override a public method from blueprint.js somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is currently (`ember-cli@2.15`) not possible. Ember CLI will always ask the user if he really wants to overwrite files unless the new file is identical to the old file.

Comment: so there is no way of avoiding this question when I want to create models and the tests - belonging to the models - using blueprint?

Comment: "creating" them won't show any question. the question is only asked if you're "overwriting" any files.